# What is the meaning of an autoregressive parameter greater than one?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima

I have created a AR(2,1,0) model with the first two parameters equal to -1.08 and -0.33. I understand that a autoregressive parameter equal to 1 implies non-stationarity and a random walk process so I'm assuming the effect is the same if the parameter is a -1. So what does it mean when the parameter is greater than one? 
This model performs pretty well so I'm not sure if something is incorrect.

Comment: @Michael For an AR(1), the absolute value of the parameter being >1 implies nonstationarity. For an AR(2) it needn't. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118019/a-proof-for-the-stationarity-of-an-ar2 (among a number of other posts)

Comment: @Glen_b, Aksakal's answer and the linked thread suggests the opposite to your first sentence. What do you think about that?

Comment: I believed Aksakal to be discussing an ARIMA(1,1,0).

Comment: Whoever closed this question, the link is irrelevant to this question. This question is about AR(2) process and the link is about AR(1) process and AR with coefficients -1.08 and -0.33 DO SATISFY the stationary condition for AR(2)! see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/118019/a-proof-for-the-stationarity-of-an-ar2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

No, autoregressive parameter greater than 1 in absolute value does not mean nonstationarity or random walk. It leads to explosive time series in most practical contexts. See, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/400781/explosive-arma-processes-are-stationary/400800#400800).

Comment: No, autoregressive parameter greater than 1 does not necessarily mean explosive time series for AR(2). see my comment above.